# Gold plating versus Silver plating for electrical contacts?

Tags: materials

I have always had it in my head that gold plated contacts were preferred.

I noticed today that the resistivity is as follows:

Silver 1.5x10<sup>-8</sup>

Gold 2.4x10<sup>-8</sup>

Is there another property that makes gold preferable to silver for use in electrical contacts?

Comment: silver tarnishes. silver oxide is still pretty conductive though but i think it is not so good for soldering. Really sucks because everyone uses silver on violin bows for prestige when stainless steel maintains a superior appearance for cheaper

Comment: Apparently the minimum switching load for gold-plated contacts is lower than that for silver nickel, silver cadmium oxide and silver tin oxide ones in relays: [Relay contact materials – does it matter?](https://www.findernet.com/en/unitedstates/news/relay-contact-materials-does-it-matter) - if that is the sort of application you meant.

Comment: Silver is good in a low/"no" oxygen environment.

Comment: @AndrewMorton ye. gold is for dry switching because it doesnt oxidize to mess up weak signals. silver cadmium oxide is good at withstanding arc corrosion for higher currents. silver tin oxide is a run of the mill cheap non toxic material for intermediate

Comment: @DKNguyen *everyone uses silver on violin bows for prestige* Interesting factoid! Maybe silver just "sounds better" ;-) I agree that it's a waste of silver.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie well, gold is too expensive for most bows and in the old days silver was easier to work or stainless steel didnt exist, with and its density helps balance bows. but there are ways around that and we are past manufacturing difficulties with stainless stel

Comment: @DKNguyen : Silver tarnish is [silver sulfide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_sulfide).

Comment: @EricTowers ah so it is. silver sulphide it is then. still pretty conductive but probably not god for soldering

Comment: Look up "wetting current" as a useful addition to the discussion.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Gold doesn't oxidize, which means that gold-to-gold contact has no extra resistance.

In other words, it isn't about the bulk resistance (the plating is very thin anyway), but about the contact resistance.

Silver is used in places where the resistance to current flow *along* a surface matters, such as the interior of a waveguide or the outside surface of a high-power RF coil. In these applications, a layer of oxidation doesn't affect performance.

Silver is also frequently used on larger RF connectors, where gold would be too expensive and not durable enough. The mechanical sliding of the contacts and threads when assembled is enough to break through any oxidation.

Comment: Give very high frequencies, skin effect and thick oxide layers, there can be an effect, like on rather old testgear.

Answer (score 4):

Gold doesn't oxidize, that is, its atoms don't lose electrons to an electron acceptor like oxygen or sulfur. There are trace amounts of hydrogen sulfide gas in the atmosphere, which is why silver tarnishes over time. The tarnish consists of a very thin layer of silver sulfide. Gold, however, is more inert than silver, and so does not combine with hydrogen sulfide, or, for that matter, oxygen. Gold's lesser ability to form non-conductive compounds, as opposed to silver's ability, trumps silver's higher conductivity.

Reference? Anyone with actual silverware or silver coins can attest to tarnish. I have a tie tack made from a silver 1949 (my year of birth) American 50-cent piece that I have to polish occasionally. My gold wedding ring doesn't tarnish.